# Fatal error: Index out of Range Swift 3.1

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

SO whats happening is when program tries to access the other 2 rows of my txt file it is blowing up, when I look in xcode under the array it shows that the rows are separated by "\t" but it just will not display the other 2 rows and well it's maddening... please see my code below any help is appreciated.

```
var dictDoc = [String:String]()
var docArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "docs", ofType: "txt")
    let fileMgr = FileManager.default
    if fileMgr.fileExists(atPath: path!){
        do{
            let fullText = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let readings = fullText.components(separatedBy: "\n") as [String]
            for i in 1..<readings.count {
                let docData = readings[i].components(separatedBy: "\t")
                dictDoc["Program"] = "\(docData[0])"
                dictDoc["Signature"] = "\(docData[1])"
                dictDoc["Extension"] = "\(docData[2])"
                docArray.add(dictDoc)
            }
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        self.title = "Word Processor Programs"
    }
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return docArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let doc = docArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\((doc as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Program")!)"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\((doc as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Signature")!)    \((doc as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Extension")!)"
    return cell
}

@IBAction func Closebtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

Comment: Can you post the text that you are trying to break down into components?

Comment: Program Signautre Extension
Word 2.0 DB A5 2D 00 DOC
MS Pub subheader FD 37 7A 58 5A 00 PUB
Acrobat plug-in 4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 API
MS Pub 58 54 BDR
WP dic 43 42 46 49 4C 45 CBD
DeskMate Doc 0D 44 4F 43 DOC
Perfect Office doc CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 00 DOC
Word doc subheader EC A5 C1 00 DOC
MS Off doc D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 DOC|DOT|PPS|PPT

Comment: it loses the formating but thats  a sample

Comment: Can you add the text to your question in the way it is supposed to be formatted.

Comment: I just tried assigning the string to a variable in playground and it's throwing an error `unprintable ASCII character found in source file` before `CBD DeskMate Doc`. Have a look at the encoding used in the file. I think that must be causing the issue.

Comment: Program\tSignautre\tExtension\n
Word 2.0\tDB A5 2D 00\tDOC\n
MS Pub subheader\tFD 37 7A 58 5A 00 \tPUB\n
Acrobat plug-in\t4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00\tAPI\\
MS Pub\t58 54 \tBDR\n
WP dic\t43 42 46 49 4C 45\tCBD\n

Comment: @PaulRaymond In for loop print the array `docData` after you initialized it may be and you get idea how many object you are having in array

Comment: it prints all the lines in the file just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from Xcode complaining about an unprintable ASCII character when copying your text, there is a subtle error in your logic: note the final newline. Which means that `fullText.components(separatedBy: "\n")` gives you *almost* what you want but with an additional empty string as the last element of the resulting array.

Possible solutions:

- Apply `trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)` to `fullText` to get rid of that pesky newline before splitting.
- Filter that empty string: `let readings = fullText.components(separatedBy: "\n").filter { !$0.isEmpty }`.

Oh, and it seems to me that `\\` between API and MS Pub should be a newline: `...API\n MS Pub...`.

**Update**

To help you track down those errors in the future and prevent your program from crashing with `fatal error: Index out of range`,
you might for instance add a `guard`:

```
...
let docData = readings[i].components(separatedBy: "\t")
guard docData.count == 3 else {
    // Ignore, log message, throw error, whatever is appropriate in your use case.
    print("Unexpected format in \(readings[i])")
    continue
}
...
```

Without handling the newline in some way, this prints

```
Unexpected format in ''
```

The `\\` I mentioned would also be shown:

```
Unexpected format in ' Acrobat plug-in  4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 API\ MS Pub 58 54   BDR'
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, DUDE YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER!!!!  I have no clue why the carriage return is being added, I mean I have tried everything to get rid of that, and then I saw this and magic happened!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. As a general note, when parsing data that you don't know for sure the precise format of, extensive checking is always a good idea. And even when you do know: everybody makes mistakes :). I have updated my answer with an example.